# If a value of a user input is in a list, how can I use this input value in a new method?

Tags: list, if-statement, indexing

Given a list ["a", "b", "c"]
followed by an empty list []

I want the user to input a value.
If this value appears on the list, I want the item to jump from the list to the empty one.
so far I got this:

```
list = ["a", "b", "c"]
empty_list = []

x = input("user_input: ")
if x in list:
     empty_list.append(list.pop(*how do I define this?*))
     print
```

the problem is: How do I define the input of the user such that it corresponds to the right index within the list?

I hope I've made myself clear.

I did not really try anything since I have no clue what to do. All I did was to look things up but so far no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO,

you didn't declare the language you are programming in, but from what I see this is Python?

You will need to figure out the list index for the value, in Python it would be `list.index(value)`. I renamed a few variables for better understandability but the code is otherwise yours:

```
allowed_inputs = ["a", "b", "c"]
given_inputs = []

x = input("user_input: ")
if x in allowed_inputs:
     given_inputs.append(allowed_inputs.pop(allowed_inputs.index(x)))
     print
```

Note however that your `print` statement does not print anything at the moment. I am not sure what you would like to print, the current contents of the `given_inputs` ?

In that case you might want to use `print(given_inputs)` instead.